# How to use Bareos (Bacula) Storage Daemon with multiple disks?

Tags: bacula

I have Bareos Storage daemon (bareos-sd) with three 2 Tb HDD. I want them to be seen as one storage and Bareos auto-switched on next disk when the previous one is full.
Now I have all disks as different Devices with different Media Type and thee Storage with the corresponding disks. In Job's Pool I set Sorage as comma-separated my three Storages. But now my first disk is full and Bareos do not use next disk.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify another device directive. Taken from http://www.bacula.org/5.0.x-manuals/en/main/main/Storage_Daemon_Configuratio.html

```
If you want to write into more than one directory (i.e. to spread the load to different disk drives), you will need to define two Device resources, each containing an Archive Device with a different directory
```

So just create another 'Device' directive, so that you have TWO device directives,  like this:

```
Device {
  Name = FifoStorage
  Media Type = Fifo
  Device Type = Fifo
  Archive Device = /folder1
  LabelMedia = yes
  Random Access = no
  AutomaticMount = no
  RemovableMedia = no
  MaximumOpenWait = 60
  AlwaysOpen = no
}
Device {
  Name = FifoStorage2
  Media Type = Fifo
  Device Type = Fifo
  Archive Device = /folder2
  LabelMedia = yes
  Random Access = no
  AutomaticMount = no
  RemovableMedia = no
  MaximumOpenWait = 60
  AlwaysOpen = no
}
```